# SAP NWDS 7.5 on other OS than Windows 10

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jco, netweaver

SAP NWDS (NetWeaver Developer Studio) is only supported on Windows 10 and only on a SAP JVM -- see also [SAP Note 2546316](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2546316)

as NWDS is actually eclipse neon with some additional SAP plugins, I wondered why.

My requirement is to run it on a **Windows Server 2008 R2**, and soon I may need to run NWDS on a recent **Mac Book Pro**.

**Current Behaviour**

- If I run it on a Windows 10 laptop, everything is fine.
- If I run it on WinServer, the thing runs like if it is a plain eclipse (not loading any SAP Plugins)

**Apparently** the NWDS is checking somewhere for the OS flavor and the JVM manufacturer.

**What I achieved so far**

- I run it on a SAP JVM using `-vm` Parameter in `eclipse.ini`
- I added `-Dos.name=Windows 10` and `-Dos.version=10.0` params, and *some* of the SAP plugins loaded -- but not all!
- In the JCo plugin folder, I tried replacing the binary files (DLL and one other file) by corresponding OS versions I got from the SAP market place)

**Questions**

1. Well, how to get NWDS 7.5 to run on Win Server (and later, on a Mac)
2. Partial achievement would be to get Eclipse to spit out more information on WHY/WHICH plugins didn't get loaded --- found no information (maybe I'm too dumb for that)

**UPDATE 20.08.2018**

Answering question 2: [Eclipse Runtime Options](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fruntime-options.html) => options *eclipse.log.**
and found the logs in the `configuration` subfolder of installation folder.

=> error is definitely not being able to load the native part of the JCo Plugin:

> org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: com.sap.jco3 [463]
>
> Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.native; native.paths:List="sapjco3.dll"; filter:="(&(osgi.native.osname~=win32)(osgi.native.processor~=x86_64))"

Comment: I assume running on MacOS will be impossible without rewriting NWDS from scratch, which is a huge task. But running on Windows Server should be possible, I ran NWDS on WinServer 2012 or 2016, don't remember the version, though I wasn't the one who installed the instance.

Comment: `If I run it on WinServer, the thing runs like if it is a plain eclipse.` What does you mean? What exact error do you get? Or give the screenshot

Comment: No error whatsoever, just all SAP plugins not loaded

Comment: @Suncatcher NWDS 7.31 worked on WinServer like a charm, need to upgrade for other reasons, though

Comment: @Suncatcher as for macOS: I don’t see a reason to rewrite “whole nwds from scratch” unless native code is used. Everything else is java code

Comment: `Everything else is java code` I assume the outcome on MacOS would be the same as you described:  just all SAP plugins not loaded.

Comment: If some plugins are not loaded, then there should be something in NWDS logs. Check [the error view and metadata folder](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/Java/NWDS+Logging+and+Tracing).

Comment: I did check the .log and error view (which have same content) that’s why I asked how I can bring eclipse to spit out more infos (denug/warnings/dependencies/whatever)

Comment: Just follow the FAQ I gave thoroughly. There had been given a SAP note with the instructions

Comment: the note 751640 gives some infos on how to get more logs out of some of the plugins (build errors when the plugins build my projects). that doesnt really help. I did find some infos in the meantime on WHY the plugin doesn't load. will update the question (answering question  2)

Comment: I wasn't aware of that note but I've certainly not had any problems running NWDS 7.5 on  Windows 7 with an Oracle JDK (all SAP plugins load without problem and the plugins I've used work fine). I've also not had an issues running it in Amazon Workspaces using their modified Windows Server 2012R2 (again, Oracle JDK).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,

the answer (at least in resp. to **Win Server 2008 R2**) is

- run on a **SAP jvm** ([Download](https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/#cloud)) using `-vm` parameter in  your eclipse.ini
- **very important**: use the `-clean` option in your eclipse.ini after switching to SAP jvm, as this will rebuild the plugin list.

The answer to the partial (logging) question is already in an update in the original question, but nevertheless:

[Eclipse Runtime Options](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fruntime-options.html) => Use options *eclipse.log.**
and find the logs in the `configuration` subfolder of installation folder.

Comment: And you did run it before not on SAP JVM??? OMG! This is the essential requirement and is specified in bold in every FAQ and manual.

Comment: Well, my first run after decompressing was **of course** on an Oracle JVM, as this is the default JVM on my machine. But I changed the used JVM as first task after that! Without the `-clean` parameter, eclipse didnt even try to load SAP Plugins on subsequent runs, unfortunately. Then I found the statement in the SAP note that NWDS **only runs on Windows 10** which lead me to idea of fiddlign with `-Dos.name` parameters (used to be a solution in the past for similar problems).